Verification of Initial Conditions in an RLC Circuit (buck converter, output voltage)
I had drawn the following circuit (note that all components are ideal and european standard):

Suppose the following Situation:

\$t<0\$: The MOSFET was open for a very long time
\$t=0\$: The MOSFET is closed

Tasks:

What is the voltage \$u_R\$ over the resistor \$R\$ at \$t=0\$ (initial condition 1)?
What is the slope of the voltage \$u_R\$ over the resistor \$R\$ at \$t=0\$ (initial condition 2)?

Question:

Could somebody please check if my derivation of the initial conditions is clear and understandable?

My Solution:

For \$t<0\$: I simplified the circuit as shown below. Since the MOSFET was off for a very long time, all voltages and currents are zero.



For \$t=0\$: I simplified the circuit as shown below. Since the voltage \$u_R\$ over the capacitor \$C\$ cannot change instantaneously, the first initial condition is \$u_C(t=0)=u_R(t=0)=0\$V. Since \$u_R=u_C\$ and \$u_C=\frac{1}{C}\cdot\int_0^{t=0} i_C(\tau) d\tau = 0\$V we get \$u_R(0)=0\$V. Differentiated both sides with respect to \$t\$ we get the second initial condition \$du_R/dt(t=0)=0\$V/s.


Thank you for your help!

NOTIFICAIONS:
I'd like to clarify the differences between this and the previous question and address the confusion about the voltage directions:
Differences Between the Questions:

Previous Question: My previous question focused on verifying the initial conditions of the inductor current in the buck converter circuit.
This Question: In contrast, my current question aims to verify the initial conditions of the output voltage, specifically the capacitor voltage, in the same circuit.

While both questions involve initial conditions in the RLC circuit, they focus on different components: the inductor current in the first question and the capacitor voltage in the second.
Directions of the Voltage Arrows (follows the European standard):
Here the convention:


Power source: The source voltage \$U_q\$ arrow pointing from the positive terminal to the negative terminal.
Load: The voltage arrow for the capacitor voltage \$u_C\$ points from the positive terminal to the negative terminal of the capacitor \$C\$.
Load: The voltage arrow for the inductor voltage \$u_L\$ points from the positive terminal to the negative terminal of the inductor \$L\$.
Load: The output voltage \$u_R\$ is taken across the load resistor \$R\$, with the arrow pointing from the positive end to the negative end.


This is very similar to your previous question in that you have gone over the same ground again in establishing the capacitor voltage so, it would help if you summarized where this question is different. Can you also explain the directions of the arrows you are using for the voltages (there was confusion in your previous question on this area as well).

Thank you for your feedback! I added a NOTIFICAIONS section at the end of my question.

@Andyaka, please see this thread, German conventions for voltages and currents are different and often caused me confusion : )

@VerbalKint the German conventions use arrows to imply electric field values rather than "straight" voltages hence the arrows are reversed compared to UK/USA and some other places. Anyway, that's what I was led to believe on a question raised a few months ago and on the OPs earlier question.

@all: is my question/notifications clear now?

@MarcoMoldenhauer what EU convention have you used because, in some EU countries, the UK and, the USA, the convention is the opposite of what you have chosen i.e. you seem to use arrows to indicate electric field direction whereas in many other places the arrow indicates voltage (with the arrow head being at the most positive end).

So should I edit my question and rotate all voltage and current arrow directions to the opposite? is it then ok?

@MarcoMoldenhauer I can't tell you because I don't know what your arrows represent. It appears to be a convention problem between UK/USA and German/other standards in these types of diagram. I'm not sure what country you originate from so I can't be sure. I can only tell you what the UK/USA does i.e. it shows arrows pointing from the lower potential to the higher potential (and not the direction of electric field). You need to be clear what your arrows mean. This doesn't apply to currents (assumed to be in the direction of conventional current).

ok I added a picture to clarify what the directions means

@MarcoMoldenhauer, I have rolled the question back. My answer does not belong in the question. You have accepted an answer, so you should reflect upon it and move on.


What is the voltage \$u_R\$ over the resistor \$R\$
at \$t=0\$ (initial condition 1)?


Since the voltage \$u_R\$ over the capacitor \$C\$ cannot change instantaneously, the first initial condition is \$u_C(t=0)=u_R(t=0)=0\$V

This is correct.
Edit:
The capacitor and resistor are in parallel, so their voltage drops must be equal and change in the same way. This is indicated in introductory textbooks about parallel and series connected elements.
End edit

Since \$u_R=u_C\$ and \$u_C=\frac{1}{C}\cdot\int_0^{t=0} i_C(\tau) d\tau = 0\$V we get \$u_R(0)=0\$V. Differentiated both sides with respect to \$t\$ we get the second initial condition \$du_R/dt(t=0)=0\$V/s.

The integral does not work here. If the inductor was a resistor instead, the answer would be incorrect. It is better to start with the derivative form of the capacitor's defining relation.
$$
\frac{du_C}{dt}_{t=0}=\frac{1}{C}i_C(0)
$$
Since \$i_L(0)=0\$, (from your previous question) and \$i_{R}=0\$ because \$u_{C}=0\$, then \$i_C(0)=0\$ as a consequence. So:
$$
\frac{du_C}{dt}_{t=0}=0
$$
Edit
From a comment

why the integral does not work here? I do not understand really

A definite integral with fixed limits of integration produces a constant result. The derivative of the result must ,therefore, be zero regardless of the function being integrated. If the inductor is replaced by a resistor, the initial rate of change will not be zero. Buts by the integration method described would still be zero incorrectly. So the integration is meaningless.
End edit

thanks a lot. So $du_C/dt(t=0)=du_R/dt(t=0)=0$, right? And can you explain to me why the integral does not work here? I do not understand really :( maybe you can add a detailed explanation in your answer? Best regards

ok thanks a lot. now it is clear.

I added a section "Solution (thanks to @RussellH):" with your solution in to my question. I wrote it a little bit different. Maybe you can check and verify if its sill correct. THX and BR marco

Looks right to me.  An easy way to verify questions of this type is simply to use SPICE.

thanks a lot for your answer. Do you thing that how I derive the second initial condition $du_R/dt(t=0)=0$V/s is really correct? I am a little bit skeptical.
